# How to override global object 'document' in jest junit test?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I want to test this class

```
export class FancyStuff extends React.Component<Props> {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.customBody = this.props.customBody ||  document.body;
    ...
```

As you can see, if I do not specify the property `customBody`, the component will try to get hold of the body of a document.

However for testing purpose, I need to ensure the `document.body` is a mock. At this stage I do not have the option to refactor the code to dependency inject the `documen`t object.

Is there anyway I can override this `document.body` globally in my unit test?

I tried something like `document = mockWindow.document;` before mounting the `FancyStuff`:

```
beforeEach(() => {

    const mockWindow = {
      document: {
        body: {
          appendChild: jest.fn(),
          insertBefore: jest.fn(),
          iamabody: jest.fn(),
        },
    }
    jest.spyOn(window, 'open').mockReturnValue(mockWindow);


  it('test fancystuff', () => {
    document = mockWindow.document;  // What I tried
    mount((
       <FancyStuffContainer/> // it uses FancyStuff
    ))
```

but I am not able to override `document.body`.

How can I do it in jest?

I am using the following versions:

```
"jest": "^23.2.0",
"jest-junit": "^5.1.0",
```